# how to trigger autoplay on splidejs on section scroll?

Tags: splidejs

I'm using splidejs and I can't find how to trigger the autoplay when the page reaches a certain section. Any thoughts?

Here's the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var splide = new Splide('.splide', {
    // Desktop on down
    perPage: 1,
    perMove: 1,
    focus: 0, // 0 = left and 'center' = center
    autoplay: 'true',
    interval: 8000,
    gap: '2.5rem', // space between slides
    arrows: 'slider', // 'slider' or false
    pagination: false, // 'slider' or false
    speed: 600, // transition speed in miliseconds
    rewind: true, // go back to beginning when reach end
    rewindSpeed: 1200,
    updateOnMove: true
  });
  splide.mount();
});
```